# Shortest way to GROUP BY similar values and retain latest rows?

Tags: mysql, sql

Sometimes I want to get just one row of each similar value, I ussually do somethingl ike this:

```
SELECT * GROUP BY Text ORDER BY Date DESC
```

My problem using GROUP to select similar rows is that I don't get the values from the latest rows in the row (I'm not quite sure what's the criteria to choosing the row that stays). I want to retain only the newest row in the group.

I know how to do it with a self join but when statements are already very long it seems a bit complicated. Is there any shorter method? Maybe using DISTINCT instead of GROUP BY?

Comment: How "newest" is defined? "Is there any shorter method" -- nope, `INNER JOIN` with nested select

Comment: Nope. The self join (or a slower correlated subquery) is the right way to do it.

Comment: Aye would have posted something like that, given a table schema.

Comment: It might have helped if you'd provided a simple example of the data and the expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to use the max function:

```
SELECT A,B,max(Date) GROUP BY Text
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a table that has multiple columns and two of which are `GroupID` and `DATE`. If you want to select the latest record for each `GroupID`, you need to have a subquery which gets the latest `Date` for each `GroupID`, example

```
SELECT  a.*             -- this just selects all records from original table
FROM    tableName a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            -- this subquery gets the latest DATE entry for each GROUPID
            SELECT GroupID, MAX(DATE) maxDate   
            FROM tableName
            GROUP BY GroupID
        ) b ON a.GroupID = b.GroupID AND
                a.Date = b.maxDate
```

*if this answer is not clear, please do ask :D*